# WebSphere and WS-Security - Not Sure Policy Sets Are Set Correctly

Tags: web-services, soap, websphere-8, ws-security

I have been struggling to learn WS-Security -- in particular how to configure and test it using WebSphere 8.5 (Full Profile). (I am using Rational Software Architect 9.5 as the IDE.)

I have run through several IBM tutorials, but I'm not satisfied that the policy sets that I create and attach to SOAP Web Service providers and clients are even being enforced when I test them.

Example: I used this tutorial on the IBM web site:

Getting Started: Using a policy set and default bindings to sign and encrypt a message (http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=matt&product=was-nd-dist&topic=twbs_getstart_policyset)

I created the policy set as described in the tutorial -- a simple one that seemingly has these characteristics:

- Timestamp sent in outbound messages
- Timestamp required in inbound messages
- Sign the request and the response (Body, WS-Addressing header, and Timestamp)
- Encrypt the request and the response (Body and Signature element in SOAP Security header)

I attached this policy set to:

- A Web Service provider set up on one local WebSphere Application Server instance (the "Provider WAS Instance")
- A Web Service client set up on another local WebSphere Application Server instance (the "Client WAS Instance").

The Web Service client also has a JSP-based testing tool that I set up using RSA's Java skeleton class creation wizard. I set the JSP-based tool to invoke the service on the Provider WAS Instance.

I set up no certificates or keys at all, since doing so wasn't part of the tutorial.

When I navigate to the JSP-based testing tool for the Web Service client, and I invoke the Web Service, I get a successful reply, with no messages about failed authentication of the signed request message, and with no messages about failed decryption of the client.

Shouldn't I be getting these kinds of errors, since I've not configured any keys or certificates or associated them with the client or provider? If not, then what are the Provider WAS Instance and the Client WAS Instance using in order to make all of this work?

I realize these are "n00b" questions, but this material has been a challenge. I would appreciate any suggestions to help me come up to speed on this topic fairly quickly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up creating a support ticket with IBM. IBM informed me that my WebSphere Application Server instance should have had application security enabled.

Application security enablement, as described on IBM's web site, says nothing specifically about the setting affecting whether WebSphere enforces Web Services security policies:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/csec_appsecurity.html

I never verified whether IBM's recommendation would work in our case, since in the interim, we elected to integrate WebSphere and Apache CXF. In any case, I hope others find this information to be useful.